# Robot is not responsive during behavior

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I have made one behavior that's purpose is to display some html page on the tablet. But when I run this behavior my robot is not responsive and I can't have a conversation with it. I don't have absolutely no idea why is this. The behavior is interactive and it is added to the default behaviors.

**Edited** Added Choreographe project Scheme

[image: Choreographe project view]

About the problem to display main html page on boot.
[How to make an HTML page to be shown when Pepper boots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812833/how-to-make-an-html-page-to-be-shown-when-pepper-boots)

Comment: Can you share the Choregraphe scheme? (the boxes)

Comment: When you say conversation with the robot I suppose you would like to speak with the "autonomous life"

Comment: @albert  Yes, also I have made my own dialog that is run by 'run_dialog_dev' from the basic channel.

Comment: I haven't used Time Boxes. Could be that the wait box makes an `sleep()` and freezes the execution of the program during the specified time?

Comment: @albert I have also tried with very simple show_html and the problem is there too.

Comment: Did you asked in the Aldebaran's forum? because I don't have any idea on finding a solution

Comment: @albert Haven't done it ye, will try it there too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a software way to start collaborative dialog: [ALDialog.runDialog()](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog-api.html#ALDialogProxy::runDialog)

So you can just create a box with the following code:

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

    def onLoad(self):
        self.dialog = self.session().service("ALDialog")

    def onUnload(self):
        self.dialog.stopDialog()

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        self.dialog.runDialog()
        #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box

    def onInput_onStop(self):
        self.onUnload() #it is recommended to reuse the clean-up as the box is stopped
        self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies in the fact that only one interactive behavior can be up and running at a time. So if you launch your behavior, then 'run_dialog_dev' has to be stopped, which means the dialog engine gets unsubscribed and so the robot is not listening anymore.

There is no system-provided way to use collaborative dialogs as part of your application. If you want to use the dialog topic you created you can use a dialog box linked to it in your "Choregraphe project Scheme" to launch the dialog and load the topic.

Comment: There is a software way to start collaborative dialog: ALDialog.runDialog()